# Uploading a file on server using Phonegap FileTransfer

Tags: cordova

I have a very strange problem when i upload a file using

```
ft.upload(fileURI,encodeURI(urlToSave) , win, fail, options, true);
```

It is not working. I never received a response from the server. I have also tried with

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
//          document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            alert ('status is ' + xhr.status);
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
}
```

atleast here i am getting a response, `File not sended successfully`. But in case of `ft.upload()` that url never hits on server.

But while using `HttpRequest` i can log the hit on server.

And one more thing when we are using `internal server` for testing `ft.Upload()` was working fine but when we have used `live server` `ft.Upload()` never succeed.

In my `config.xml` i have whitelisted all the urls like below

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

Any idea what would be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

try my code

javascript

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "file";
options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
var params = new Object();
params.productId = data.productId;
params.imageLink = data.productId + "_1";
options.params = params;
options.chunkedMode = false;
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(imageURI, "https://example.com/upload.php", win, fail, options);

function win(r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
    //alert(r.response);
    window.location.replace("#linkshare");
}

function fail(error) {
    $.mobile.loading('hide');
    navigator.notification.alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code, null, 'Alert', 'OK');
}
```

php

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 'https://example.com/uploads');
```

Comment: In my code there is no difference as you have posted. And My server side code is in `.Net` i cant use `PHP`. BTW do you have any idea why it works on internal server but not on the live server.